# Integrity Measurement - TPM-bypass

Tags: linux, security, tpm

I am digging into Integrity Measurement Architecture and try to enable it on an embedded device.

I have enabled the IMA related configuration flags and compiled the kernel. I can now see xattr `security.ima` and can set hashes or signatures via `evmctl`.
Running signed files works after loading the keys into `_ima` keyring.
On first sight it doesn't look too bad.

But when I check the logs I can see an error message during boot up:

> IMA: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!

In this question I am not addressing the issue why the TPM is not found, but I would like to know, what are the consequences?

What does TPM-bypass mean in the end?

I assume there will be some functionality missing but I cannot find any information what TPM-bypass means and what will be affected.

One issue I face is that the file /sys/kernel/security/ima/ascii_runtime_measurements only shows one line and does not grow.

Is that related to the TPM-bypass and what else should I expect?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read IMA is totally useless without a TPM chip most likely TPM-bypass is just included in the code so users can test the software but it wont provide any real protections

Maybe you can try a TPM emulator like https://github.com/PeterHuewe/tpm-emulator if you just want to test

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I am not sure what this means in the end. Executing binaries that are not properly signed or hashed is prevented by IMA even with TPM-bypass.